# How can i use normal CAN with CAN FD?

Tags: embedded, stm32, embedded-linux, can-bus, nxp-microcontroller

I'm working with i.MX6ULL not supporting CAN FD but other CAN nodes supports. How can i use normal CAN on this bus without making any hardware changes?

Best regards.

I need to fix CAN to CAN FD communication compability.

Comment: You can't have CAN "classic" and CAN FD _traffic_ on the same bus. If you need to make other hardware changes, then that depends on what CAN transceivers you are using. You need to provide more details and this doesn't really seem like a programming question either, but rather a question for https://electronics.stackexchange.com